# query is not working correctly

Tags: mysql

I have these tables:

**single_user_has_university_has_course**

```
single_user_users_id_user   university_has_course_university_id_university  university_has_course_course_id_course  first_year_school   last_year_school grade
1                                               1                                            1                             2000             2001            15
```

And

**university_has_course**

```
university_id_university    course_id_course
    1                           1               <<< I want to select this
    15                          1
    1                           3
    15                          3
```

The problem is that the query below return all rows where `course_id_course = 1 but ignore the`university_id_university = 1`. Then, will return two rows.

**query:**

```
    SELECT A.first_year_school, A.last_year_school, A.grade, U.university, C.course, T.type_course
    FROM single_user_has_university_has_course A

    INNER JOIN university_has_course Q
    ON A.university_has_course_course_id_course  = Q.course_id_course

    INNER JOIN university U
    ON Q.university_id_university  = U.id_university 

    INNER JOIN course C
    ON Q.course_id_course = C.id_course

    INNER JOIN type_course T
    ON C.type_course_id_type_course = T.id_type_course

    AND A.single_user_users_id_user = ?
```

Comment: Those column names are horrid. You should really consider making them more concise and easier to understand to save headaches in the future.

Comment: What are you trying to select here?  You say you're trying to select the course_id_course rows (btw who names a column `university_id_university` or `course_id_course` instead of just `university_id` or `course_id`?).  You need to rephrase your question so that it is readable and clearly conveys what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I would like to know why the down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are joining the last table to the previous joins on 2 constraints `C.type_course_id_type_course = T.id_type_course AND A.single_user_users_id_user = ?`. I think you want to write it as a WHERE clause. So replace your last line with:

```
WHERE A.single_user_users_id_user = ?
```

But you're not also trying to filter `university_id_university = 1`, so you may want to add it to the `WHERE` clause as well:

```
WHERE A.single_user_users_id_user = ? AND Q.university_id_university = ?
```

Comment: I need two conditions in the first inner join. However i will accept. thanks